# Having problem with mutability of Rc pointers

Tags: rust, smart-pointers

I'm trying to implement a simple tree structure with `Rc` pointers:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}

enum Expr {
    B(i128),
    A(Rc<Expr>, Rc<Expr>),
    O(Rc<Expr>, Rc<Expr>),
}

struct Node  {
    data: Rc<Expr>,
    parent: Option<Rc<Node>>,
    children: Vec<Rc<Node>>,
}

impl Node {

    fn add_to_children(mut self, node: &Rc<Node>) {
        self.children.push(Rc::clone(node))
    }

    fn set_as_parent(mut self, node: &Rc<Node>) {
        self.parent = Some(Rc::clone(node))
    }

    fn link_parent_child(parent: &mut Rc<Node>, child: &mut Rc<Node>) {
        println!("eheeh");
        
        parent.add_to_children(&child);
        child.set_as_parent(&parent);
    }

}
```

This won't compile however:

```bash
error[E0507]: cannot move out of an `Rc`
  --> src/main.rs:32:9
   |
32 |         parent.add_to_children(&child);
   |         ^^^^^^^-----------------------
   |         |      |
   |         |      value moved due to this method call
   |         move occurs because value has type `Node`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves value
  --> src/main.rs:21:28
   |
21 |     fn add_to_children(mut self, node: &Rc<Node>) {
```

What's the better way of implementing this type of tree? It is my signature that's wrong?

Comment: Have you read https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/index.html#introducing-mutability-inside-of-something-immutable?

Comment: @ChayinFriedman Is this the usual way to go ? To box pointers inside one another ? Seems to me more a hack. It is the only way to allow shared references and mutability ?

Comment: `RefCell` is not a pointer, and this may be considered a hack, or a workaround (many times many Rust programmers will view it as such), but in this case the problem is not in Rust but in your code that you should re-design to avoid shared mutable state.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman How can you avoid having shared references in a graph where the nodes can be simply integers that update ?

Comment: For example, by using indices. This is a very common approach to graphs in Rust. This can also have better cache locality.

Comment: I'd ask myself if there's a way to leverage an existing library. Linked Lists/Trees are hard and error prone in Rust. (In every language, actually, in Rust it just becomes more visible; and Rust doesn't have a garbage collector that magically disposes of circular references)

Comment: @Finomnis thank you for your answer, I'm sure that there are several very good libraries, I will try to take inspiration from them. My final goal is not the tree, I'm trying to make a minimal tree-like structure that implements only the behaviour I need, I don't necessarily want all that comes with a full Tree library.

Answer (score 1):

Your `add_to_children` and `set_as_parent` methods take `mut self`, which means they consume `self` and try to move out of the `Rc`. That's not allowed, as there may be other references to the object.

The methods should take `&mut self`... but you'll run into another issue: `Rc` only exposes an immutable reference. Because, again, there may be multiple references.

The way to solve that issue is interior mutability. In your case, `RefCell` is the easiest - it's essentially a single-threaded lock, allowing only one place mutable access at a time. It is not a pointer and does not allocate on the heap by itself - it simply wraps the underlying value.

There's also another issue: Because both your parent and children refer to each other via `Rc`, you end up with a circular reference, meaning your nodes won't free memory when you drop them. Using `std::rc::Weak` for the parent references will fix that.

As Chaymin Friedman points out, Rust's rules about mutability can make implementing a tree structure somewhat difficult, especially when it contains parent references. There are many crates out on `crates.io` that have implemented such tree structures, using a variety of techniques.